# Cannot convert values ​into mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, xampp, interface-builder

I want to enter the value of a variable into a MySql database, but it is giving me this error:

[image]

I use code like this:

```cpp
ADOQuery1->SQL->Clear();
ADOQuery1->SQL->Add("insert into data_nasabah(nama_nasabah,tanggal,debit/kredit,saldo,no_rekening)values('"+ns[0].nama+"','"+Date()+"','"+ns[0].dk[0]+"','"+ns[0].saldo[0]+"','"+rekening[n]+"')");

ADOQuery1->ExecSQL();
```

Comment: `debit/kredit` is not a valid name for a column in SQL. Because of the `/` character.

Comment: @dratenik actually, `debit/kredit` is valid in MySQL, but it needs to be quoted as `\`debit/kredit\`` or `"debit/kredit"`, see [9.2 Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) in MySQL's documentation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, I didn't know that. Seems like a bad idea though (case in point: this question :) ).

Answer (score 0):

Column names that have special characters in them need to be quoted with `` ` ``, or `"` in `ANSI_QUOTES` mode. See [9.2 Schema Object Names](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifiers.html) in MySQL's documentation.

Try this:

```cpp
ADOQuery1->SQL->Text = "insert into data_nasabah (nama_nasabah, tanggal, `debit/kredit`, saldo, no_rekening) values ('" + ns[0].nama + "','" + Date() + "','" + ns[0].dk[0] + "','" + ns[0].saldo[0] + "','" + rekening[n] + "')";
```

However, **don't** format SQL statement parameters manually like you are! This is subject to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You can use `Sysutils::QuotedStr()` (or `Sysutils::AnsiQuotedStr()`) to avoid this, eg:

```cpp
ADOQuery1->SQL->Text = "insert into data_nasabah (nama_nasabah, tanggal, `debit/kredit`, saldo, no_rekening) values (" + QuotedStr(ns[0].nama) + "," + QuotedStr(Date()) + "," + QuotedStr(ns[0].dk[0]) + "," + QuotedStr(ns[0].saldo[0]) + "," + QuotedStr(rekening[n]) + ")";
```

But, you really should be using a [parameterized query](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_Parameters_in_Queries) instead, let the database engine handle the quoting for you, eg:

```cpp
// make sure to set ADOQuery1->ParamCheck=true beforehand!

ADOQuery1->SQL->Text = "insert into data_nasabah (nama_nasabah, tanggal, `debit/kredit`, saldo, no_rekening) values (:PNamaNasabah, :PTanggal, :PDebitKredit, :PSaldo, :PNoRekening)";

ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("PNamaNasabah")->Value = ns[0].nama;
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("PTanggal")->Value = Date();
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("PDebitKredit")->Value = ns[0].dk[0];
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("PSaldo")->Value = ns[0].saldo[0];
ADOQuery1->Parameters->ParamByName("PNoRekening")->Value = rekening[n];

ADOQuery1->ExecSQL();
```